# Building Multilingual Web Sites with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, multilingual

I am making a Multilingual Website with ASP.NET using visual studio 2008. In my application i want to make support for different languages for that i need to create resource files for each language . After designing the page, i went to Tools and then selected Generate Local Resource but i am not able to generate Local resource file .

I am getting an error :"Start creating resource content and adding 'meta' attributes to server controls and directives.
A resource writer could not be found.
Finished creating resource content and adding 'meta' attributes."

And am not getting the Local resource file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added/changed the globalization attribute in web.config?

```
<system.web>
  <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="auto" uiCulture="auto"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: No i have not added this code.. where do i have to add these ?